# How to model "index" list vs "show" details in GraphQL?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, graphql

My data model has two resources: `Folder` and `Messages`. Each message belongs to a folder. Sometimes I'll want to get a list of folders (including some fields for each folder). Sometimes I'll want to get the details of a particular folder (including some fields and messages for that folder).

In a Rails/RESTful system, this would correspond to the `index` and `show` actions on the `Folder` resource; the latter would receive the `id` parameter specifying the desired folder. What would this schema look like in "idiomatic" GraphQL?

One approach might be have one field for each action:

```
type Query {
  folders: [Folder]
  folder(id: String!): Folder
}
```

There's some duplication here, which seems messy and makes it harder for an client to introspect and understand the schema.

Perhaps the duplication can be removed with a nullable argument:

```
type Query {
  folder(id: String): [Folder]
}
```

If an `id` is passed, just the details of that `Folder` will be returned (as a one-item array). If `id` is `nil`, then it'll get the details for all folders. This overloading seems to add some hidden complexity.

Which approach is "better practice"? Is there a better way to model this situation?

Comment: Any retrospectives thoughts on this? I have a lot of models where both detail and list views are gonna be used. I'm all up for approach 2, because it is simpler to implement and keeps the schema half the size. Did any issues arise, like the detail routes being expected by the clients and not found?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Fields are cheap, use them.

I'd suggest the first approach. In the same way a REST API can get hopelessly muddled with flags to trigger different behaviors, so can a field with various arguments. By making two different fields, you can also let the type system give stronger client guarantees:

`type Query {
  folders: [Folder!]!
  folder(id: String!): Folder
}`

In this case, you'll always get some sort of list back for `folders`, and it won't contain any `null`s. Emptiness is just the empty list. The API documents itself, which may not be the case if you try to mash an increasing number of optional arguments into one field.

Also, if you need to paginate `folders`, you'll need pagination-specific arguments for that endpoint, and perhaps the intermediate structure of the [connection pattern](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-connections.html).

Answer (score 0):

I use the second approach. In this way, you can add more arguments to the same endpoint later on. Maybe a folder has a path or you like to filter on creation date.